# Widen Python boxplot

Tags: python, boxplot

I'm new to Python and I have problem with box-plot size.

I need to show the brand of phones and their batteries. However, the box-plot is not wide enough to show names of all brands.

I would like do it with this command:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(x='Brand', y='BatteryCapacity', data=df)
```

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?